# MySql stored procedures: How to select from procedure table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say we have a stored procedure selecting something from a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE database.getExamples() 
SELECT * FROM examples;
```

How can I use the result from this procedure in a later select?
(I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM (CALL database.getExamples())
```

but with no success.) 
Should I use SELECT... INTO outVariable in the procedure? Or should I use a function returning the table instead?

Comment: Trying to find a solution, I'm trying the following, but obviously the return data type ('TABLE') doesn't work;
<pre>
CREATE PROCEDURE database.getExamples(
   OUT examplesTable TABLE /* <<< What datatype to use for a table? */
) 
SELECT * FROM examples INTO examplesTable
</pre>
Am I on the right track here..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a stored procedure/function return a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reformulated the question in this thread: [Can a stored procedure/function return a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/mysql-can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table). 
Obviously, it isn't possible without the use for temp tables.

Comment: What makes it so obvious that it's not possible without temp tables? This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @circuitry The grammar makes it clear that MySQL doesn't allow `select * from getExmaples() ...`.  It doesn't necessarily mean there's no other way to do it.  This is a frustrating issue;  in PostgreSQL, it's easy to `select * from getExamples() ...`.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(OID int IDENTITY (1,1),
VAr1 varchar(128) NOT NULL,
VAr2 varchar(128) NOT NULL)

Populate temporary table

INSERT INTO #TempTable(VAr1 , VAr2 )
SELECT * FROM examples
```

Comment: Thank you Dani!
This means that I have to rebuild the entire table every time?
That seems like lots of extra work to me. Just running CALL getExamples() obviously gives the data I need - the question is how to access it in a select statement...

Comment: This is SQL Server code. 
in mysql - you can create temporary table use it, and then drop it.

Comment: From performance aspect, and I'm not a pro, i think it will be almost the same as using it in a nested statement, there probably some optimization possibilities in the nested option, but unless you are dealing with very large/complicated select you won't notice it.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you want to do. I guess it is possible, need to try it myself though.

Answer (score -4):

In **SQL server** you can then do `SELECT * FROM database.getExamples()`

If you want to re-use the 'procedure' then, yes, I would put it into a table valued function.

Otherwise you could just SELECT INTO a #temporary table inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi RR! I'm trying this, but obviously the data-type "TABLE" isn't valid:

CREATE PROCEDURE database.getExamples( 
OUT examplesTable TABLE /* <<< What datatype to use for a table? */ ) 

SELECT * FROM examples INTO examplesTable

Comment: SQL Server = Microsoft SQL Server and it has different capabilities from MySQL. This means a lot of things you can do in MS SQL cannot be done in MySQL and vice verse. OP asks for MySQL.