# Can a stored procedure/function return a table?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

Can a MySql stored procedure / function return a table without the use of temp table?

Creating the following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE database.getExamples() 
    SELECT * FROM examples;
```

and later calling it with

```
CALL database.getExamples()
```

displays the example table - just as expected - but the following doesn't seem to be possible:

```
SELECT * FROM CALL database.getExamples()
```

Is it possible at all to return a query result table from a stored procedure / function, and if so - how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As for now, this is not possible.

Here is the [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) on what may be used in the `FROM` clause:

```
table_references:
    table_reference [, table_reference] ...

table_reference:
    table_factor
  | join_table

table_factor:
    tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint)]
  | table_subquery [AS] alias
  | ( table_references )
  | { OJ table_reference LEFT OUTER JOIN table_reference
        ON conditional_expr }

join_table:
    table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
  | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor

join_condition:
    ON conditional_expr
  | USING (column_list)

index_hint:
    USE {INDEX|KEY} [FOR JOIN] (index_list)
  | IGNORE {INDEX|KEY} [FOR JOIN] (index_list)
  | FORCE {INDEX|KEY} [FOR JOIN] (index_list)

index_list:
    index_name [, index_name] ...
```

As you can see, stored procedures are not in this list.

Comment: Isn't table reference a possible solution? because when you pass a subquery it also gives a table reference so it might be true that is not possible but I think the reason is not the schema you postet

Comment: @Niton I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Comment: I mean the documentation you posted does not say that it is not possible to us a procedure/function. Because you see you can use a "table reference" (which is as i think the thing a sub query returns). And so if the DBMS supports procedures returning table references, it would be possible to use them in selects even if it is not directly stated by the documentation

Comment: @Niton yes it does say that. Do you know how to read grammar description in BNF?

Answer (score 10):

According to [*A.4 MySQL 5.6 FAQ: Stored Procedures and Functions*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-stored-procs.html):

> #### [A.4.14: Can MySQL 5.6 stored routines return result sets?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#faq-mysql-can-routine-results)
>
> Stored procedures can, but stored functions cannot.

Comment: Jakub is correct.. If you create a stored procedure and not a function it will return a result set.

Comment: @TomT but how to consume such a resultset with SELECT ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html still does not allow procedures in FROM

Comment: @Arioch'The I think that's the more important question, too.  :(

Comment: Maybe a clarification and summary on the link: The stored procedures CAN return result sets to be consumed by back-end callers (like JAVA, C#, etc.), each SELECT statement resulting in separate result-set. However, locally it may NOT be possible (i.e. in MySQL Workbench you can see the result of a stored proc on your screen as a result set, but you CANNOT return a table to the caller of the stored proc (unless you use an OUT variable for each returned value and recombine the result in a table-row, which may be argued as a being flexible and practical)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it can be done, but with use of output variables from the stored procedure.
http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_SELECT.php

```
-- 1. Create Procedure
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_students_SELECT_byPK` 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_students_SELECT_byPK
(
    IN   p_student_id                    INT(11)       , 
    OUT  p_password                      VARCHAR(15)   , 
    OUT  p_active_flg                    TINYINT(4)    , 
    OUT  p_lastname                      VARCHAR(30)   , 
    OUT  p_firstname                     VARCHAR(20)   , 
    OUT  p_gender_code                   VARCHAR(1)    , 
    OUT  p_birth_dttm                    DATETIME      
 )
BEGIN 

SELECT password                      , 
       active_flg                    , 
       lastname                      , 
       firstname                     , 
       gender_code                   , 
       birth_dttm                    
INTO   p_password                      , 
       p_active_flg                    , 
       p_lastname                      , 
       p_firstname                     , 
       p_gender_code                   , 
       p_birth_dttm                    
FROM   students
WHERE  student_id = p_student_id ; 

END 

GO

-- 2. Select Results from Stored Procedure
/***
IN    p_student_id   INT(11)
OUT   p_password     VARCHAR(15)
OUT   p_active_flg   TINYINT(4)
OUT   p_lastname     VARCHAR(30)
OUT   p_firstname    VARCHAR(20)
OUT   p_gender_code  VARCHAR(1)
OUT   p_birth_dttm   DATETIME
***/

CALL sp_students_SELECT_byPK
(
  8, 
  @p_password , 
  @p_active_flg , 
  @p_lastname , 
  @p_firstname , 
  @p_gender_code , 
  @p_birth_dttm
)
GO

SELECT @p_password      AS p_password      , 
   @p_active_flg    AS p_active_flg    , 
   @p_lastname      AS p_lastname      , 
   @p_firstname     AS p_firstname     , 
   @p_gender_code   AS p_gender_code   , 
   @p_birth_dttm    AS p_birth_dttm   
GO
```

Comment: This is what I had exactly my thought. You posted as an answer already. +1

Comment: This looks like to return an array than a table.

Answer (score 2):

Each SELECT statement that does not insert into a table or a variable will produce a result set.

If you want your stored procedure to return only one result set, make sure that you only have one SELECT statement. If you have other SELECT statements, make sure that they insert results into a table or variable.

UPDATE
Here are examples of stored procedures.

This stored procedure would return one result set:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE stored_procedure_name()
BEGIN
    DECLARE local_variable_name INT;

    SELECT column_name FROM table_1 LIMIT 1 INTO local_variable_name;

    SELECT * FROM table_1;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
This stored procedure would return two result sets:

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE stored_procedure_name()
BEGIN
    DECLARE local_variable_name INT;

    SELECT column_name FROM table_1 LIMIT 1 INTO local_variable_name;

    SELECT * FROM table_1;

    SELECT * FROM table_2;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Ref:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8291/how-does-mysql-return-a-result-set-from-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do what you are attempting by using a view instead of a stored procedure, but that entirely depends on what the stored procedure does.

If using a temp table is your only option, consider using the MEMORY storage engine.