# How to fetch result of stored procedure in iReport?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ireport

I am using Ubuntu 12.04,iReport-4.7,MySQL,mysql-jdbc driver

I write stored procedure in MySQL

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE first()
BEGIN
select * from person where id in (11,22,33);
END //
DELIMITER;
```

which return `id` & `name` as fields
& calling it from iReport

```
select id+1,name from (call first)
```

gives me syntax error,

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'call first)' at line 1
```

but when I run `call first` in query executor,no error

How should I get required field for further calculations ?
Does this is possible in MS-SQL ?

Comment: maybe you need to add alias on your id+1 coolumn something like id+1 Id,name from etc...

Comment: @BizApps,I tried with select (a.id+1) as b,a.name from (call first)  as a,but it says same syntax error near 'call first)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

You might consider to use temp table.

Please check this SO Post: [MySql: Can a stored procedure/function return a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/mysql-can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table)

Regards

Comment: '@BizApps',The link you give,I try to understand MySQL manual,but not,sorry for that.Its much more complex,only understandable by experts.Can you elaborate in more details ?,if possible in reference with my question

Comment: try to check this: http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_SELECT.php