# Update using a procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've spent all day trying to get this to work.

I have a procedure that performs calculations on dates based on an occurrence type. It returns two new datetime fields from a SELECT.

I want to use this procedure to update an events table. Something like this.

```
UPDATE
    events
SET 
    start = new_start,
    end = new_end
FROM CALL updateEvents(events.occurance, events.day_num, start, end)
WHERE
    end < NOW();
```

I'm using MySQL workbench but it reports that 'FROM' is not valid input at this position.

Here is the procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `updateEvents`(occurance VARCHAR(20), day_num INT, start_time DATETIME, end_time DATETIME)
BEGIN
    DECLARE time_interval INT;
    DECLARE new_start DATETIME;
    DECLARE last_day DATETIME;
    DECLARE last_hours INT;

    SET time_interval = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time);
    SET last_hours = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(start_time));
    SET last_day = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(start_time)) + last_hours, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s");
    SET new_start =
        CASE occurance
        WHEN 'daily' THEN DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        WHEN 'weekly' THEN DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
        WHEN 'monthly' THEN DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        WHEN 'bimonthly' THEN DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
        WHEN 'quarterly' THEN DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)
        WHEN 'firstof' THEN
            CASE
                WHEN DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s'), INTERVAL (7+day_num - WEEKDAY(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s')))%7 DAY) > start_time
                THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s'), INTERVAL (7+day_num - WEEKDAY(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s')))%7 DAY)
                ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s'), INTERVAL (7+day_num - WEEKDAY(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s')))%7 DAY)
            END
        WHEN 'secondof' THEN
            CASE
                WHEN DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s'), INTERVAL (7+day_num - WEEKDAY(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s')))%14 DAY) > start_time
                THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s'), INTERVAL (7+day_num - WEEKDAY(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s')))%14 DAY)
                ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s'), INTERVAL (7+day_num - WEEKDAY(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01 %H:$i:$s')))%14 DAY)
            END
        WHEN 'lastof' THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN DATE_SUB(last_day, INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(last_day)+7-day_num))%7 DAY) > start_time
                THEN DATE_SUB(last_day, INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(last_day)+7-day_num))%7 DAY)
                ELSE DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(last_day, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL ((WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(last_day, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))+7-day_num))%7 DAY)
            END
    ELSE
        start_time
    END;
    SELECT
        new_start,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(new_start) + time_interval,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS new_end;
END
```

PS. excuse my mis-spelling of occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: [Can a stored procedure/function return a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table)

You have to write the UPDATE statement inside of the procedure...
good luck