# Insert each row of stored procedure into a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures in MySql. One of them does the calculation and returns everything in groups. With another stored procedure, I have a WHILE statement that runs for each month and calls the first stored procedure. I want to get the result of each group and save them in a table.

The code is something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `first`(IN `start` date, **it should be list of items** )
begin 
    SET result = 0;
    
SELECT 
    item.name,
    sum(amount) *INTO result*

FROM
    FOO
        INNER JOIN
    BAR ON id = id
WHERE
        date(someDate) < date(start) 
group by something;
end
```

And the runner is something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `runner`(IN `from` date, IN `to` date)
BEGIN
    set dateTo = date(to);

    set dateFrom = date(from);

    WHILE DATE(dateFrom) <= DATE(dateTo) DO

        call first(dateFrom, @res);

// here I need another loop through all results of the first procedure to insert each one of them in the following line.

        insert into table_x (**some values which have been returned**);
                
        SET dateFrom = DATE_ADD(dateFrom, INTERVAL 1 month);
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Did you note this:  [Can a stored procedure/function return a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table), and is there a good reason to split this into two stored procedures?

Comment: i can't see why a loop i can't see hwy you make the second quey but mysql doesn't return tbales, you can only make a temporary table and use that

Comment: @Luuk the problem is not having two procedures but having a loop over a select statement. I'm doing other stuff in the runner as well and that's why I separated some of the functionalities into another procedure.

Comment: Frankly, I hardly ever use stored procedures in MySQL anyway. Writing equivalent code in application languages like Java, Python, even Perl is always easier, and always more scalable. I'm often surprised at how many questions there are on SO about using procedures in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don-' think that the loop and the second procedure ist really necessary

MySQL can't return table arrays or something of that kind, but you can use temporary tables

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `first`(IN `start` date )
begin 
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTABLE
SELECT 
    item.name,
    sum(amount) 

FROM
    FOO
        INNER JOIN
    BAR ON id = id
WHERE
        date(someDate) < date(start) 
group by something;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Outer procdudre

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `runner`(IN `_from` date, IN `_to` date)
BEGIN
    set dateTo = date(_to);

    set dateFrom = date(_from);

    WHILE DATE(dateFrom) <= DATE(dateTo) DO

        call first(dateFrom, @res);



        insert into table_x (SELECT * FROM myTable);
                
        SET dateFrom = DATE_ADD(dateFrom, INTERVAL 1 month);
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You ca make dynamic sql work with different variables

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `first`(IN `_start` date , IN _group varchar(100))
begin 
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;
SET @sql := CONCAT("
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTABLE
SELECT 
    item.name,
    sum(amount) 

FROM
    FOO
        INNER JOIN
    BAR ON id = id
WHERE
        date(someDate) < date(",_gRoup,") 
group by",_goup,";");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. I need to insert each group (each line of the select statement) into a table. If the result is just a row, I can do that. But when it gets grouped by, I can't. Because of having multiple lines.

Comment: For each month, I have different groups. The WHILE in second procedure is only responsible for different months of the year. The loop that I need in first procedure (or after the call of first procedure) is responsible for different categories.

Comment: you can add mpre vattoables to the mix, but you need then dyamic sql

Comment: see added exxample for group, but as your colplte code gets mire and more complicated, but now you have a good start

Answer (score 0):

This might work, if all `** some values **` are replaced.

Minimal version of MySQL needed is 8.0 (or an equivalent MariaDB version).

The two variables `@from` and `@to` are set to let this script know from which data to which date is needed.

This code is untested, because OP wrote `"I have two stored procedures in MySql"`, but he uses things like "** some values **", which make the two stored procedures invalid (sigh).

Final remark: It is, of course, possible to wrap this complete statement into a stored procedure. (If above corrections are made)

```
set @from = '2021-05-01';
SET @to   = '2021-06-13';

insert into table_x (** some values **) 
WITH recursive dates AS (
   SELECT @from as d
   UNION ALL
   SELECT date_add(d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   FROM dates
   WHERE d<@to
   )
SELECT d, **some values which have been returned**
FROM dates
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 
      item.name,
      sum(amount) 
   FROM
      FOO
   INNER JOIN
      BAR ON id = id
   WHERE
      date(someDate) < date(d) 
group by something) sq
```