# Translate SQL server Stored Procedure which returns value to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure wrote in SQL Server that I need to convert to MySQL, which has this code inside.

```sql
SQL server code

declare @resultatSP table (...);
...

insert into @resultatSP execute other_procedure(...);
...
```

My problem is that in SQL Server, the "result" of the **last select** done in the SP **other_procedure** is stored in **@resultatSP**. (I don't know if it is conventional but it works), but I cannot reproduce it in MySQL.

I tried things like this:

```sql
MySQL code

drop temporary table if exists resultatSP;
create temporary table resultatSP (...);

...

resultatSP = CALL other_procedure(...);
```

OR

```
CALL other_procedure INSERT INTO resultatSP;
```

But nothing works.

I read that in MySQL, call stored procedure does not return result and we must use **OUT/INOUT** parameters. But I cannot change the **other_procedure(...)**.

What is the most confusing is that this **other_procedure** has been convert in MySQL and it is used in java with some Javax.persistance annotations as **@NamedNativeQuery** or **@SqlResultSetMapping** and these annoations succeed to get the "result" of the last *select* of the stored procedure **other_procedure(...)** converted in MySQL. I don't know how these annotations make it.

Comment: You used a "trick" on the TSQL side to combine resultsets - lucky for you. But the insert/exec logic has no direct translation into MySQL dialect. The short answer is, as best I can determine, is to change your code design to match what MySQL can support. Simple searching will find many discussions about capturing the resultset of a procedure for use outside of that procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert each row of stored procedure into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959692/insert-each-row-of-stored-procedure-into-a-table)