# Storing MySQL Stored Procedure Result Into Temporary Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In SQL Server, I used to create a table variable to store results from a certain stored procedures. This is how I usually do with table variable.

```
DECLARE @My_Table_Variable TABLE(col_1 FLOAT, col_2 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @My_Table_Variable(col_1, col_2) EXEC [My_Procedure]'param_1','param_2'
```

Now, while using MySQL, I recognized that table variable doesn't exist. I've seen some questions related to this, for instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table) says it's not possible to `SELECT` something `FROM` a procedure.

How about temporary table? Can we `CALL` a procedure, and then put the result into a temporary table? With the syntax something like this:

```
CALL my_procedure('my_first_parameter','my_second_parameter') INTO my_temporary_table;
```

which allows me to query from `my_temporary_table`. Is this possible to be performed?

Comment: Noway. Add temptable with predefined name creation/insertion into SP code.

Comment: Do you mean that I create and insert into the table within the procedure?

Comment: *create and insert into the table within the procedure* Of course. Use temptable (it is specific for a connection, and it is autodropped when connection is closed).

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you.