# Calling a stored procedure in a "with" statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL and I want to use a "with" statement to read the output of another stored procedure in a query, but I realized that it throws an exception when I try to use "CALL sp_2()" in a "with" statement.

This one works well:

```
CALL sp_2(user_input);
```

But this one doesn't:

```
WITH A AS (CALL sp_2(user_input))
SELECT * FROM A;
```

Am I doing something wrong, or MySQL really doesn't allow "WITH" statements to use other stored procedures? Is there any other solution?

Comment: [Docs say no](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions) under "A WITH clause is permitted in these contexts:"

Comment: Yes, and Yes. You can't call a procedure and consume its output like this, a "with" statement is how you define a "common table expression" which is essentially a wrapper for a SQL query to be combined with the parent query. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table) perhaps.

Comment: @Stu Is there any way to store the output of a stored procedure?

Comment: @NewUser did you read the linked question & answers?

Comment: @Stu It says "Stored procedures can, but stored functions cannot", but we are already talking about stored procedures not functions. I am running a "select" query in "sp_2"

Answer (score 1):

MySQL stored procedures return a result set. In fact, they return *multiple* result sets. That is, you can run several SELECT queries in one procedure. Each one returns a separate result set. So the client that called the procedure must loop over result sets.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html says:

> To write C programs that use the CALL SQL statement to execute stored procedures that produce result sets, the CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS flag must be enabled. This is because each CALL returns a result to indicate the call status, in addition to any result sets that might be returned by statements executed within the procedure.

Below is an example of a procedure that returns two result sets. I'm running this in the MySQL command-line client, which automatically processes the multiple result sets.

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> create procedure p()
    -> begin
    -> select 123 as foo;
    -> select 'abc' as c1, 'xyz' as c2;
    -> end//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> call p;
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-----+-----+
| c1  | c2  |
+-----+-----+
| abc | xyz |
+-----+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

So how can this be called from a CTE or a subquery? Answer: it cannot. Each CTE or subquery can only run a one SELECT statement that returns a single result set.

The only way to call a procedure is using the CALL statement from a client, or from another stored routine (procedure, function, trigger, or event).

So how can you save the result of a stored procedure?

Typically, fetch the result set(s) to your client application, and do whatever you want with the data in your code.

If you need to do further SQL queries on the result data, you may write code in your client app to insert data into a temporary table. Or you could write the procedure itself to save its results to a temporary table instead of returning them as a result set.