# Calling a user defined stored procedure from select statement mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select

I am trying to call a user defined stored procedure from a select statement and its giving me an error. However when I call a system procedure it works just fine. Is there a way to call a user defined procedure from a select statement. This is for mysql

```
SELECT ID, email FROM user PROCEDURE simpleproc();
```

give me an error ERROR 1106 (42000): Unknown procedure 'simpleproc'

```
mysql> call simpleproc();
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

where as

```
SELECT ID, email FROM user PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

works

Comment: It is not possible to select from stored procedure the way you wrote in your question. see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629324/mysql-stored-procedures-how-to-select-from-procedure-table) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/mysql-can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table).

Comment: I can see how this could be confusing, `PROCEDURE ANALYSE` is not a stored procedure see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/procedure-analyse.html

Answer (score -23, accepted):

<strike>You can call stored procedure from select statement</strike>,To call a procedure you must use following syntax:

```
CALL stored_procedure_name (param1, param2, ....)
```

Such as, you can CALL following procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure1`(IN var1 INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT var1 + 2 AS result;
END//
```

as

```
CALL procedure1(10);
```

Check this site for reference: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

Comment: Yes - This is how you call a stored procedure. But were is the select statement ?